# Solve matlab "Matrix dimensions must agree" error

Tags: matlab, matrix, filter

i've been trying to do this question but no matter how i go about it i get this error.

any ideas ?

The question is

[image]

"Matrix dimensions must agree"

```
bb = [1,1.18,1]; %-- Filter Coefficients
nn = 1:150;
L2 = 0:9; % M - 1(10-1 = 9)

%1st at 0.3
w1 = (0.2*cos(0.44*pi*nn)) .* (exp(-1i * 0.3 * 3.14 * L2)) ;

%2nd at 0.44
w2 = 0.2*cos(0.44*pi*nn) .* exp(-1i*0.44*3.14*L2);

%3rd at 0.7
w3 = 0.2*cos(0.44*pi*nn) .* exp(-1i*0.7*3.14*L2);

wt = w1 + w2 + w3;

HTOTAL = freqz(bb, 1, wt); 

H1 = freqz(bb, 1, w1); %

H2 = freqz(bb, 1, w2); %

H3 = freqz(bb, 1, w3); %

%set the value of x to see the filter
x = 1;

subplot(2,1,1); plot(wx, abs(HH))
subplot(2,1,2); plot(wx, angle(HH))
xlabel('Normalized Radian Frequency')
```

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to element-wise multiply `(0.2*cos(0.44*pi*nn))` by `(exp(-1i*0.3*3.14*L2))`. The issue here is that the first array contains `nn = 150` elements, while the second contains `L2 = 10` elements.

Looking at the original question, it looks like you're required to use a filter length (`L2`) of 10, but your `nn` array ranges from 1 to 150 instead of the required 0 to 9.

You should use `(0.2*cos(0.44*pi*L2))` instead of `(0.2*cos(0.44*pi*nn))` to fix your "Matrix dimensions must agree" error.

Comment: Hey mate thanks for the tip !!!
that makes sense, i had thought i was meant to keep the same range from the question prior il give that a wizz.

Comment: Although now in getting the error with freqz in that the Options must be character vectors or real, numeric, scalar or vector values. 

which im assuming is because of the .* against the exponential
sorry to be  a pain but do you have any tips for that as well :/

Comment: Looks like you're passing the wrong variables into `freqz()`. The third argument should be a single value, but you're trying to pass in a vector (`wt/w1/w2/w3`). Do you still need to use `bb` for this question? If not, it might make more sense if you simply used `freqz(wt, 1);` (without `HTOTAL` too).